# Speedy search for JAXB object

Tags: performance, dom, jaxb, benchmarking

In my own benchmark and also in other web links, JAXB is faster for parsing XML files compared to the DOM library. However, when I tried to search for a JAXB object from its root object, its speed is disappointing compared to DOM.

For search with JAXB, I used the Apache JXPath library, i.e., the JXPathContext class and its getValue() method. Comparatively, for search with DOM, I used the Document class and its getElementsByTagName() method. My benchmark shows that the former is much slower than the later.

So here is a dilema, if I want to parse XML files fast, I want to use JAXB, but if I want to search for a node object quickly, I have to use DOM. I am wondering whether there is an optimal way to do both, for example, a faster method for JAXB object search or JAXB tree traveling than the JXPath.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Am I missing the obvious here?

JAXB marshals to Java objects. Java objects can carry methods. Such as a search method. Which would be a lot faster than having to rely on a heap of introspection to sniff out annotations for a generic method, since, well you can skip irrelevant parts of your XML by default. Even better: you can optimise the data structures themselves (the Java objects) for specific search queries.

Comment: Thanks for the good point. I certainly can add a dedicated search method into the root java class, but that's not as nice as the DOM library has. I was wondering whether there is a generic way to search for object in JAXB, like the DOM Document class with similar performance, or at least faster than the JXPath library.